# Missing type annotation for props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following code base and I was able to successfully give a type to the prop being passed

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { signin } from '../../assets/images';
import PinkButton from '../shared/button-color-pink';
import Input from '../shared/Input-field';
import ImageDiv from '../shared/Image-div';
import FormDiv from '../shared/Sign-in-div';
import { NunitoItalic18, Nunito20 } from '../shared/nunito/nunito';
import ImageContainer from '../shared/image-container';

const SignIn = props => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <ImageContainer>
      <ImageDiv bg={signin} src={signin} alt="logo" />
    </ImageContainer>
    <FormDiv>
      <Input style={{ marginTop: 44 }} placeholder="Username" />
      <Input style={{ marginTop: 44 }} placeholder="Password" />
      <PinkButton style={{ marginTop: 45, width: 100 }}>Sign in</PinkButton>
      <NunitoItalic18 style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
        Forgot username or password
      </NunitoItalic18>
      <Nunito20
        style={{ marginTop: 187, cursor: 'pointer' }}
        onClick={() => props.setDisplayScreen('SignUpOptions')}
      >
        Don’t have an account? Sign up
      </Nunito20>
    </FormDiv>
  </div>
);

SignIn.propTypes = {
  setDisplayScreen: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default SignIn;
```

When I run yarn flow it gives me the following error: `` Missing type annotation for `props`. ``
How can I fix this?

It seems flow might be having a problem with react?

Comment: is this tsx or jsx ?

Comment: You does not mentioned which types of props is going to come

Answer (score 0):

You need to add type annotations to props of your component.

Like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMZ6RayqgDkWJ5tA3IoqbAHYDOeAysgDmnAJKdQAXlAAKdFXTcAXKADeAH1DdCOACLJu6aMQCefUg0Kdl03lmSdBASkkA+UKmQAPQgBNQagF9nCTdpRFBQAB4fZAA3TRxjaEIJFRVQGIMjY2VaGEJPWlAAgIiuAGFoZFIAa1TpYLc5WAUAOi1dfUMTMwtOaVoBYQBVdAB5dBxkLm5aRwCXcKjgGNjFx1ZEAsxcDMJIYgBXaH4hUU5mIA).

Minimal example:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

const SignIn = (props: {| setDisplayScreen: (string) => mixed |}) => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}  onClick={() => props.setDisplayScreen('SignUpOptions')}>
  </div>
);

export default SignIn;
```

I don't know what exactly type of `setDisplayScreen` you want to be, you may want to change it.